# GAE(Spring Boot App) CORS check not returning Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-boot, cors

I have spent the whole day trying to deploy a Spring Boot Application (REST API) to Google App Engine, and I am stuck trying to get past the CORS configuration.

The spring application works locally so I know that Spring CORS configuration is correct.

However, I get the following error when I deploy to GAE.

Failed to load https://avian-infusion-156317.appspot.com/api/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

The below are the exchanged headers from Chrome Developer Tools:

General

```
Request URL:https://avian-infusion-156317.appspot.com/api/login
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:172.217.26.52:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Request Headers

```
:authority:avian-infusion-156317.appspot.com
:method:OPTIONS
:path:/api/login
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
access-control-request-headers:content-type
access-control-request-method:POST
origin:http://localhost:8100
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
```

Response Headers

```
allow:GET, HEAD, POST, TRACE, OPTIONS
alt-svc:hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"
content-length:0
content-type:text/html
date:Wed, 03 Jan 2018 16:22:06 GMT
server:Google Frontend
status:200
x-cloud-trace-context:7369ca471aca5fe01fb46903e9af3b9f;o=1
```

As you can see, the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is missing from the response.

I have set the cors configuration on GAE as follows:

```
gsutil cors get gs://avian-infusion-156317.appspot.com
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["*"], "origin": ["*"], "responseHeader": ["content-type", "authorization"]}]
```

Before resorting to * for origin, I have tried the specific URL, namely 'http://localhost:8100' to no avail.

What am I missing?  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to troubleshoot this problem.  It turns out that this has nothing to do with CORS configuration.  None of my controllers, and hence the REST endpoints, were online.  Being a newbie on Google App Engine, there was one thing that I completely misunderstood.

I had a delusion that Google App Engine had it's own layer of CORS in addition to the application, which wasn't true.

I compared the quickstart spring boot example and my project, and the one thing that I was missing that made it all work was ServletInitializer.

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

Adding this class at the same root package as the Application made the controllers be online.  I hope this is helpful to someone else having a similar issue.